# Making lights out

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I could really use some help with understanding where I am going wrong with 2d list comprehension. I have spent hours and the finer points of why its not working out continues to elude me.

The following code is a very basic [Lights out game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) that takes an input

```
runGenerations2d([0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0])
```

Sets up a game board N x N

with a click it needs to change the value of the clicked box.

I believe the problem is
    setNewElement

is taking x,y data and the rest of my functions haven't a clue what to do with the values passed on

```
import time # provides time.sleep(0.5)
from csplot import choice
from random import * # provides choice( [0,1] ), etc.
import sys  # larger recursive stack
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) # 100,000 deep


def runGenerations2d(L , x = 0,y=0):
    show(L)
    print( L )           # display the list, L
    time.sleep(.1)      # pause a bit
    newL = evolve2d( L )   # evolve L into newL
    print(newL)
    if min(L) == 1:
        #I like read outs to be explained so I added an extra print command.
        if x<=1: # Takes into account the possibility of a 1 click completition.
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i click to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        else:
            print ('BaseCase Reached!... it took %i clicks to complete' % (x))
            print (x)
            done()#removes the need to input done() into the shell
        return   
    x = x+1 # add 1 to x before every recusion
    runGenerations2d( newL , x,y )  # recurse

def evolve2d( L ):
    N = len(L)  # N now holds the size of the list L
    x,y = sqinput2()  # Get 2D mouse input from the user
    print(x,y) #confirm the location clicked
    return [ setNewElement2d( L, i,x,y ) for i in range(N) ]


 def setNewElement2d( L, i, x=0,y=0 ):
    if i == (x,y): # if it's the user's chosen column,
        if L[i]==1: # if the cell is already one
            return L[i]-1 # make it 0
        else: # else the cell must be 0
            return L[i]+1 # so make it 1
```

The error after a click

```
[None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None]
The data does not seem 2d.
Try using sqinput instead.
```

Comment: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: Don't know the game, don't know what you are trying to do, don't know what doesn't work. Need more details!

Comment: @ Paul Evans, Julien Bernu ..Is this a bit more clear i've done quiet a bit of editing?

Comment: Can you state the *exact* problem in a sentence or two?

Comment: @Tom Dalton ... When I click in the window it needs to change the value of the clicked cell from a 1 to a 0 or vice versa. This was easy enough in a 1D list... now that its 2d list the function `setNewElement2d`  somewhere is not able to convert a clicked cell into that changed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNewElement2d` returns a single number but the calling code is expecting two numbers.

This line

```
return [ setNewElement2d( L, i,x,y ) for i in range(N) ]
```

Is setting i to 0, then 1, then 2, ... then N-1. These are single numbers.

You then compare the single numbers to two numbers on this line:

```
if i == (x,y):
```

You seem to be assuming i is an x,y pair but it isn't.

Here's how to create every x-y pair for a 3x3 grid:

```
# Makes (0,0),(0,1)...(2,2)
[(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
```

I think this code is closer to what you want, still might need changing:

```
def evolve2d( L ):
    N = len(L)
    x,y = sqinput2()
    print(x,y)
    return [setNewElement2d(L, xx, yy, x, y) for xx in range(N) for yy in range(N)]


 def setNewElement2d( L, xx, yy, x=0,y=0 ):
    if (xx,yy) == (x,y): # if it's the user's chosen row and column
        # If it's already 1 return 0 else return 1
        return 0 if L[xx][yy]==1 else 1
```

Comment: That makes alot more sense now. Any ideas on how to avoid the for loop and stick to recursion?

Comment: If you wanted to do recursion you'd need to increment x and y to point to the next cell. But the for loop solution is easier to read. It will also run faster. There is an overhead to function calls (especially in Python), so recursion should only be used where it makes code clear; it wouldn't make this clearer.